# Error when retrieving records

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm a beginner in ASP.NET MVC. I'm getting a error while trying to retrieve records from the database.

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   does not contain a definition for 'CategoryName'

**LINQ to SQL Class:**
[image]

**Model:**

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class CategoryRepository
    {
        private BusDataClassesDataContext dc = new BusDataClassesDataContext();

        public List<tblCategory> GetAllCategory()
        {
            return dc.tblCategories.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
 public class CategoryController : Controller
 {
        //
        // GET: /Category/
        CategoryRepository cat = new CategoryRepository();

        public ActionResult ViewCategory()
        {
            var category = cat.GetAllCategory().ToList();
            return View("ViewCategory", category);
        }

  }
```

**View:**

```
<p>
Category Name:<%=Html.Encode(Model.CategoryName)%>
</p>
<p>
Description:<%= Html.Encode(Model.Description)%>
</p>
```

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Comment: @chamara- Did my solution help resolve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `List<tblCategory>` to the view. Hence the `Model` here will be the `generic list`. That is the reaons why you are getting the error message:-

`'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'CategoryName'`

Did you intend to pass tblCategory or else did you intend to iterate thought the model to get to each tblCategory?

You can do this way

```
<% foreach(var category in Model)
{%>
<p>
Category Name:<%=Html.Encode(category.CategoryName)%>
</p>
<p>
Description:<%= Html.Encode(category.Description)%>
</p>
<% } %>
```

On a little bit different note.
You are already returning the type as GenericList in your method.

```
 public List<tblCategory> GetAllCategory()
        {
            return dc.tblCategories.ToList();
        }
```

You don't need to again perform an ambiguous `.ToList()` conversion.

```
var category = cat.GetAllCategory().ToList();
```

Comment: I'm trying to iterate through records in tblCategory and display on the view

Comment: yes it's from the ViewCategory view. I'm getting a error when trying you'r solution. please see the update

Comment: Is this your partial view or main view? Are you getting the model with values when you debug? Try using @category.CategoryName this is a scope issue now.

Comment: it's the main view and i'm getting the model.

Comment: Try using For loop instead of foreach and do Model[i].Description.. This is some bizzare scope issue now. are you able to see category object inside foreach

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28630/discussion-between-pscoder-and-chamara)

Comment: Thanks.got it working with Ankit Singh answer. Can you please modify your code so that i can accept your code as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use this::

**`<% foreach (var category in Model)`**

ruther than  ::

**`@foreach (var category in Model)`**

in the view.

Like This

```
<% foreach (var category in Model)
   { %>
<p>
    Category Name :<%=Html.Encode(category.CategoryName)%></p>
<p> 
    Description :<%=Html.Encode(category.Description)%></p>
<% } %>
```